# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.14.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have many trouble with old version with tensorflow. I using open source but it's used old library. So i trying to install the old tensorflow but i get in trouble when pip install tensorflow==1.14.0. Because fix each bug in old library time consuming than try to download old packages so i want to install old tensorflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using conda

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.14
```